# Add item in dynamic reactive form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to build a nested reactive form in Angular 5. I am able to push items at one level, but unable to push item at second level.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  customerName: '',
  email: '',
  items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
});
}

 createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: 'a',
      description: 'b',
      price: 'c',
      //subItems: this.formBuilder.array([this.createSubItem()])
    });
 }

 //createSubItem(): FormGroup {
    //return this.formBuilder.group({
      //subname: 'abc'
    //});
 //}

 addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    //this.subItems = this.items.get('subItems') as FormArray;
    //this.subItems.push(this.createSubItem());
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
 }
```

In the above code the uncommented code is working fine with push. I have further subItems inside items, and commented code is the one I am trying to achieve, but it is not working.

Can any body show me how to achieve this?

For uncommented code, I am showing data in html like this and it is working well. If any body have solution at code level, please also tell me how to update html for nested items as well.

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
<div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
      <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description">
      <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="sldkj" (click)="addItem()">
</form>
```

**SOLUTION:**

First of all I managed to pre-populate values like this.

```
 obj = [
    {
      'name': "umair",
      'description': "desc1",
      'subItems': [
        {
          'subname': 'value'
        },
        {
          'subname': 'value2'
        },
        {
          'subname': 'value3'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': "ali",
      'description': "desc2",
      'subItems': [
        {
          'subname': 'valu4'
        },
        {
          'subname': 'value5'
        },
        {
          'subname': 'value6'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm(this.obj);
    console.log(this.orderForm);
  }

  createForm(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      arr.push(this.createItem(obj[i]));
    }
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array(arr)
    });
  }

  createItem(obj): FormGroup {
    var subArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.subItems.length; i++) {
      subArr.push(this.createSubItem(obj.subItems[i]));
    }
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: obj.name,
      description: obj.description,
      subItems: this.formBuilder.array(subArr)
    });
  }

  createSubItem(subItem): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      subname: subItem.subname
    });
  }
```

After help in 'marked' answer below, I managed to add subitem and populate in html like below.

```
 <form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  <!-- <label>{{item.get('name').value}}</label> -->
  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.controls.items.controls; let i = index;">
    <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
      <!-- <label>{{item.get('name').value}}</label> -->
      <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
      <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description">

      <input type="button" value="subAdd" (click)="addSubItems(i)">

      <div formArrayName="subItems" *ngFor="let subItem of item.controls.subItems.controls; let idx = index;">
        <div formGroupName="{{idx}}">
          <!-- <label>{{subItem.get('subname').value}}</label> -->
          <input formControlName="subname" placeholder="Item name">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

code

```
addSubItems(_index: any): void {
    var a = this.orderForm['controls']['items']['controls'][_index] as FormGroup;
    this.subItems = a.get('subItems') as FormArray;
    var newSubItem = {
      'subname': 'value6'
    }
    this.subItems.push(this.createSubItem(newSubItem));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first let start with understanding what you do.

You make a formarray in formarray. So this mean it have **two loops**. So you have to *ngFor the first and *ngFor the second. In the end this means you have an **index** **i** for your items and and **j** for your subItems. Then you can add `addSubItems(i)` for pushing your subItems.

Your html should look something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  <div formArrayName="items">
     <div *ngFor="let arrays of orderForm.controls.items.controls; let i = index;">
        <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
          <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
          <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description">
          <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price">
          <input type="button" value="subAdd" (click)="addSubItems(i)"> <-- here your button -->
          <div formArrayName="subItems">
             <div *ngFor="let item of arrays.controls.subItems.controls; let j = index;">
                <div formGroupName="{{j}}">
                   <input formControlName="subname" placeholder="Item subname">
```

Your addSubItems should look something like:

```
 addSubItems(_index: any): void {
    this.item = this.orderForm['controls']['items']['controls'][_index] as FormGroup;
    this.subItems = this.item.get('subItems') as FormArray;
    this.subItems.push(this.createSubItem());
```

Comment: Can you please show in ts file if we have array of items and each item has array of subitems. How to pre-populate this form?

Comment: And what would be written in addSubItem function.

Comment: I added the function I'm not 100% sure if it's going to work like that but should look something like this (I only make the form onLoad with multiple subArrays). To give you an idea.

Comment: Ya, it worked with 1 modification. question updated.

Comment: Your welcome and ty now I can try this in my application to lol.

Comment: Thanks, Btw I managed to pre-populated values as shown in question solution.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce amount of code, these can little refactored `addSubItems(index) to addSubItems(item)`:

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  ...
  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.controls.items.controls; let i = index;">
      ...
      <input type="button" value="subAdd" (click)="addSubItems(item)">
  </div>
  ...
</form>

addSubItems(item: FormGroup): void {    
    this.subItems = item.get('subItems') as FormArray;
    var newSubItem = {
      'subname': 'value6'
    }
    this.subItems.push(this.createSubItem(newSubItem));
  }
```

So, no need to find item by index: `var a = this.orderForm['controls']['items']['controls'][_index] as FormGroup;`, because you are already can pass `item: FormGroup`

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-item-in-dynamic-reactive-form-in-angular)

Comment: thanks @Yerkon for the StackBlitz Demo. Well explained and simple to understand. I was able to add an array of form groups following this example. +1 added to this answer!