# Creating nested form, from given JSON data with N level

Tags: angular, angular5

I have to build a form in Angular5 based on received JSON data from the backend. The data has nested structure and can contain N level.

For example, level one has {key, type}, and if its type = 'choose', it has another property {key, type, values}, the second level is *values* has {value, fields}, the third level *fields* .. etc

Here is a sample of the data https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmgxjd

For now I just need the typescript code, then I will work on the HTML one.

PS: I think it should be reactive form, because the user can add or delete data from the interface

Comment: Is the JSON always the same or can it change with multiple levels and multiple choosens?

Comment: @Swoox It can change with multiple levels and multiple choosens.
for example if the type of the field is 'choose', then this level has second level called values

Comment: I posted an answer plz look at the other answer for reactive form ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling working on such kind of problem few hours ago. I posted it on another thread and figured out the solution (under my solution heading) and the answer given. This might help you as well.

[Add item in dynamic reactive form in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666593/add-item-in-dynamic-reactive-form-in-angular)

Comment: Thank you .. I added another levels proccessing
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674396/4157073

Comment: N-level should be achieved using recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, bear with me I'm not going to make the code for you I will just give an example with some text.

So what you do is you make a consistent JSON.

```
fields = [ 
  {key: 'abc', type 'text'}, 
  {key: 'abc', type 'text'}, 
  {key: 'abc', type 'text'}, 
  {key: 'abc', type 'choosen', fields: [
    {key: 'abcd', type 'text'}, 
    {key: 'abc', type 'choosen', fields: [
      {key: 'abcde', type 'text'} 
    ]} 
  ]} 
]
```

Ok now we have an JSON array that can have multiple layers.

Now for every level you going to make one component in your maincomponent:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <div *ngIf="field.key !== choosen">
  <-- what ever you want to do with key put here -->
  <subFields [data]="field.fields" (returnData)="returnData($event)" *ngIf="field.key === choosen"><subfields>
```

The `@Input() data: any;` will be your next fields in your child component. And `@Output() returnData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();` to send data back to your parent.

The html of your child component will look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of data">
  <div *ngIf="field.key !== choosen">
  <-- what ever you want to do with key put here -->
  <subFields [data]="field.fields" (returnData)="returnData($event)" *ngIf="field.key === choosen"><subfields>
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended this answer [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672252/4157073) from two levels to 4 levels. but still hope that we can convert the code to be able to accept N level (N is unknown), like making it using recursive functions.

Here is the answer with 4 levels https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmgxjd

Comment: Hi @Hala Ba, the stackblitz does not show anything. The component 'HTML' is blank.