# Unable to patch data to FormArray

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, formarray

Unable to patch values to FormArray `resultList`.

Anybody can please explain me, what i'm missing?

**TS File:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../student';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.css']
})

export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  studList: Student[] = [];
  myform: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    lastName: new FormControl(),
    gender: new FormControl('male'),
    dob: new FormControl(),
    qualification: new FormControl(),
    resultList: new FormArray([])
  });    

  onSave() {
    let stud: Student = new Student();
    stud.firstName = this.myform.get('firstName').value;
    stud.lastName = this.myform.get('lastName').value;
    stud.gender = this.myform.get('gender').value;
    stud.dob = this.myform.get('dob').value;
    stud.qualification = this.myform.get('qualification').value;
    this.studList.push(stud);
    this.myform.controls.resultList.patchValue(this.studList);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.studList));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
export class Student {
    public firstName: String;
    public lastName: string;
    public gender: string;
    public dob: string;
    public qualification: string;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Striped Rows</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped" formArrayName="resultList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of myform.controls.resultList.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td><p formControlName="firstName"></p></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**this.studList JSON:**

```
[  
   {  
      "firstName":"santosh",
      "lastName":"jadi",
      "gender":"male",
      "dob":"2018-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
      "qualification":"BE"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"santosh",
      "lastName":"jadi",
      "gender":"male",
      "dob":"2018-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
      "qualification":"BE"
   }
]
```

Comment: check my answer that might resolve your issue

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: @PranayRana No.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By your question you want to add new `Student` to `resultList`.
First of all, you need to know `FormArray` is an array of  **AbstractControl**.
You can **add** to array only type of **AbstractControl** not other.
To simplify task prefer to use `FormBuilder`:

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  createForm() {

    this.myform = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      lastName: [],
      gender: ['male'],
      dob: [],
      qualification: [],
      resultList: new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

As you can see before filling  **resultList** `FormArray`, it's mapped to **FormGroup**:

```
onSave() {
    let stud: Student = new Student();
    stud.firstName = 'Hello';
    stud.lastName = 'World';
    stud.qualification = 'SD';
    this.studList.push(stud);

    let studFg = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [stud.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      lastName: [stud.lastName],
      gender: [stud.gender],
      dob: [stud.dob],
      qualification: [stud.qualification],
    })
     let formArray = this.myform.controls['resultList'] as FormArray;
    formArray.push(studFg);
    console.log(formArray.value)
  }
```

> **FormBuilder** - Creates an **AbstractControl** from a user-specified
>   configuration.
>
> It is essentially syntactic sugar that shortens the **new FormGroup()**,
>   **new FormControl()**, and **new FormArray()** boilerplate that can build up
>   in larger forms.

Also, in html **formControlName** bound to `<p>` element, It's not an input and you can't bind to not form elements like **div/p/span**...:

```
 <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of myform.controls.resultList.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td><p formControlName="firstName"></p></td> <==== Wrong element 
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

So, I think you just want to show added students in table. Then iterate over **studList** and show it's value in table:

```
<tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of studList; let i = index" [formGroupName]=i>
                    <td>
                        <p> {{item.firstName}} </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

### Patching value

Take care when patching array. Because [patchValue](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1402-L1409) of **FormArray** patches values by the **index**:

```
 patchValue(value: any[], options: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}): void {
    value.forEach((newValue: any, index: number) => {
      if (this.at(index)) {
        this.at(index).patchValue(newValue, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent});
      }
    });
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
  }
```

So, code below it patches the element at **index=0**: First indexed value of `this.myform.controls['resultList'] as FormArray` will be replaced with:

```
let stud1 = new Student();

stud1.firstName = 'FirstName';
stud1.lastName = 'LastName';
stud1.qualification = 'FFF';
formArray.patchValue([stud1]);
```

Your case doesn't work because patchValue **requires** some **controls** in array. In your case there is no controls in array. Look source code.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-add-new)

Comment: Good example. This should work. If you have time look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666593/add-item-in-dynamic-reactive-form-in-angular/49667898?noredirect=1#comment86347676_49667898

Answer (score 6):

[First try with this steps and make sure are you on correct way](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName)

Because in your scenario you are patching the object to formArray ,so you have to parse that object first & check once have you imported ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts.

Answer (score 4):

you have to co like this , code is taken from [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#buttons), you need to do setcontrol that will do or go though link there is code for the same it makes uses of Address array

```
 this.setAddresses(this.hero.addresses);

  setAddresses(addresses: Address[]) {
    const addressFGs = addresses.map(address => this.fb.group(address));
    const addressFormArray = this.fb.array(addressFGs);
    this.heroForm.setControl('secretLairs', addressFormArray);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer using `FormBuilder` to create form.

```
export class ComponentName implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.buildForm();
    }

    buildForm() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            ...
            resultList: this.fb.array([])
        });
    }
}
```

I believe the studlist will be obtained through API call as an observable rather than an static array. Let's assume, we data as follow.

```
resultModel = 
{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    ....
    resultList: [
       {
            prop1: value1,
            prop2: value2,
            prop3: value3
       },
       {
            prop1: value1,
            prop2: value2,
            prop3: value3
       }
       ...
    ]
}
```

Once the data is available, we can patch the values as follow:

```
patchForm(): void {
        this.form.patchValue({
            firstName: this.model.firstName,
            lastName: this.model.lastName,
            ...
        });

        // Provided the FormControlName and Object Property are same
        // All the FormControls can be patched using JS spread operator as 

        this.form.patchValue({
            ...this.model
        });

        // The FormArray can be patched right here, I prefer to do in a separate method
        this.patchResultList();
}

// this method patches FormArray
patchResultList() {
    let control = this.form.get('resultList') as FormArray;
    // Following is also correct
    // let control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['resultList'];

   this.resultModel.resultList.forEach(x=>{
        control.push(this.fb.group({
            prop1: x.prop1,
            prop2: x.prop2,
            prop3: x.prop3,

        }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array does not contain `patchValue` method. You have to iterate over controls and `patchValue` 
each of them separately.

Comment: can you explain with sample example

Comment: @ritaj, wrong. FormArray has method `patchValue` [example](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#example-2) and [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1402-L1409)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `formgroup` in `formarray` as:

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      clientCode: new FormControl('', []),
      clientName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]{0,50}$/)]),
      type: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      description: new FormControl('', []),
      industry: new FormControl('', []),
      website: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.settings.regex.website)]),
      businessEmail: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(this.settings.regex.email)]),
      clients: this._formBuilder.array([this._formBuilder.group({
        contactPerson: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        contactTitle: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        phoneNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.settings.regex.phone)]),
        emailId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.settings.regex.email)]),
        timeZone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.settings.zipCode), Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(12)])
      })])
    })
```

For patch value I am using below method as:

```
let control = _this.formGroup.get('clients') as FormArray
        clients.forEach(ele => {
          control.push(_this._formBuilder.group({
            contactPerson: new FormControl(ele.client_name, [Validators.required]),
            contactTitle: new FormControl(ele.contact_title, [Validators.required]),
            phoneNumber: new FormControl(ele.phone_number, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(_this.settings.regex.phone)]),
            emailId: new FormControl(ele.email_id, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(_this.settings.regex.email)]),
            timeZone: new FormControl(ele.timezone, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(_this.settings.zipCode), Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(12)])
          }))
        });
```

Using this method we can validate the nested field as well.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

First create your form based on your retrieved data structure then use `patchValue`;

the form needs to contain all form controls before applying `patchValue`.

let's say your data has a property containing an array of string you do

pseudo-code:

```
for ( const item of data.myArray ) {

  form.controls.myArray.push( new FormControl('') )

}
```

then

```
form.patchValue(data);
```

this example doesn't make mush sense as you could directly initialize the data inside the `for` loop but for more complex forms this will make you avoid parsing through all keys an data types to initialize the values.